# How can I share RAM module via network in C++?

Tags: c++, network-programming, resource-management

**Just I need to know is there any way to share multiple RAM modules for hosting a client system?**

I used to write an infinitive calculation app that's used 1 mb from another pc in network by making a simple server client connection and spreading parallel tasks and then gather up the results to the target system; but now I need something to manipulate the ram storage directly. Is there anything available for that like toolkit or sdk or something? it can be in all c family languages.

Comment: What you're describing "shared ram via network" sounds very close to what [memcached](https://memcached.org/) is all about. But the problem you are describing doesn't sound like you need to access memory storage on other nodes directly, but rather just have a way to do message passing between nodes.  I'm not sure

Answer (score 2):

You are confused.

First, [RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory) is not used (directly) by [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)). It is the [operating system kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) which manages RAM and provide [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space)s to processes thru virtual memory (so your program, running in a process, has its virtual address space). Read a good textbook like [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to understand these concepts.

**There is no way to share RAM across network**, and that would make no sense (because the bandwidth and latency of RAM is a lot better than that of network). Relative to the speed of RAM, the network is many thousands times slower (so is always a bottleneck) !

You might design your software as some [distributed computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing) using [message passing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) between processes running on several hosts.

**You have a lot to learn**; look into [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce), [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface), [sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets), [0mq](http://zeromq.org/) etc etc....

You probably want to use Linux or POSIX (because it is dominant in distributed or cloud computing). Read some Linux programming book like [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) or something newer, then see [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and the many `man` pages they refer to. Notice that [socket(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html), [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html), [tcp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) (and other [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)) are highly relevant to your needs.

You might want to use some [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database). Perhaps [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system), [PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org/), [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/), [REDIS](https://redis.io/) or even [memcached](https://memcached.org/) might be useful.

You need to learn and read a lot of things before coding.